# Can we prevent Entity Framework to save Child Entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hello I have a class:-

```
public class Property
{
  public virtual ICollection<PropertyUrl> Property_URLs { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<BrochureData> Property_Brochures { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<ImageSortOrder> Property_ImageSortOrders { get; set;}

}
```

When I am saving Property, I also have data loaded in Child Entities. Can I stop Entity Framework from saving Child Entities. Is there any setting ? The reason I want to do this is I want to do some additional processing and I have separate repository for Child Entities to do all this.

Comment: @SailBand so these child entities will eventually get saved manually?

Comment: a way could be saving parent entity manually and calling the repository and saving child entities first

Comment: can you provide some details whether this is a `ManyToMany` or `ManyToOne` relationship?

Comment: there's no switch or config that will prevent EF from saving related entities, you can save child entities manually to perform additional processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[NotMapped]` [annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-properties#data-annotations) to exclude a property. For example

```
public class Property
{
  [NotMapped] 
  public virtual ICollection<PropertyUrl> Property_URLs { get; set; }

  [NotMapped]
  public virtual ICollection<BrochureData> Property_Brochures { get; set; }

  [NotMapped]
  public virtual ICollection<ImageSortOrder> Property_ImageSortOrders { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: he eventually wants to save these not exclude them

Comment: from question "The reason I want to do this is I want to do some additional processing and I have separate repository for Child Entities to do all this"

Comment: by doing `[NotMapped]` EF will exclude these and won't treat them as foriegn key relationships

Comment: @Aarif Yes that is what he wants: 'Can I stop Entity Framework from saving Child Entities.'

Comment: If someone wants no to save child entities then why those properties are called "child entities"

Comment: So what would your answer be then?

Comment: I've added some comments on the question, I'd need more information to give a proper answer